# I want to dynamic arrays on the basis of the required. is it possible in python and yes then how?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dynamic

Well, I want to create dynamic arrays with the help of the points which stores data in different arrays. I have thousands of data and they stores in various arrays so can anybody help me in this task?

For example

```py
xy = np.array([[116,2306],[518,2007],[346,1517],[146,2310],[110,2289],[456,1000],[527,1009],[580,201],[539,1862]])

xv = []
yv= []
max_min_x = []
max_min_y = []
for i in range(len(xy)):
    x = [xy[i][0]]
    xv.append(x)
    y = [xy[i][1]]
    yv.append(y)



for i in xv[0]:
    for j in yv[0]:
        max_min_y.append(j-60)
        max_min_y.append(j+60)

    max_min_x.append(i-60)
    max_min_x.append(i+60)


#print(max_min_y)

group1 = []


for i in xv[0]:
    for j in yv[0]:
        max_min_y.append(j-60)
        max_min_y.append(j+60)

    max_min_x.append(i-60)
    max_min_x.append(i+60)
    for i in xy:
        if  i[0] in range(max_min_x[0],max_min_x[1]) and i[1] in range(max_min_y[0],max_min_y[1]):
            pair = [i[0],i[1]]
            group1.append(pair)    
        else:
            pair = [i[0][1]]
print(group1)
```

I want to create dynamic array which stores else data into another array.
[else condition data].

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? It's hard to guess it from your description.

Provide desired ouput.

Comment: What a difference with your previous question?

Comment: I want to make this thing as a dynamic. I do this manually for small points but I have a lots of points and I want to put these points in a group according to range.